# tkinter scroll not working on a canvas of variables

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a issue with getting the whole thing to scroll when I run it and make it smaller it scrolls correctly but then when I click the make field button I am not able to scroll to see all of the fields. I am trying to get it so I can scroll through potentially thousands of questions that will be generated by another function I am working on but I wanted the interface to work before I continued working on the back-end information.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Form_Data:
    Text_entry = None
    fields = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'DOB', 'Email','Contact', 'Last Name', 'DOB', 'Email','Contact', 'Last Name', 'DOB', 'Email','Contact', 'Last Name', 'DOB', 'Email','Contact']
    values = []
    directory = ""
    Form = None
    def get_directory(self):
        return self.directory

    def set_directory(self, Folder):
        self.directory = Folder
    
    def get_fields(self):
        return self.fields
    
    def form_set(self, form):
        self.Form = form

def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field = entry[0]
      text  = entry[1].get()
      print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))
    


def makeform(root, Data):
    
    
    
    if Data.Form != None:
        for item in Data.Form:
            item[1].destroy()
            Data.Form == None
        for item in Data.Text_entry:
            item[0].destroy()
            item[1].destroy()
            Data.Text_entry == None
            #item.entry.delete(0, 'end')
    entries = []
    entriestext = []
    
     
    for field in Data.fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
      
      entriestext.append((row, lab))
    root.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    sb = Scrollbar()  
    #sb.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
    #sb.config( command = rows.yview, background = 'bisque' )
    Data.Text_entry = entriestext
    Data.Form = entries
    print(Data.Form)





if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Learn To Code at Codemy.com')
    root.geometry("500x400")
    Data = Form_Data
    # Create A Main Frame
    main_frame = Frame(root)
    
    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    # Create A Canvas
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    # Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
    my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    # Configure The Canvas
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
    # Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
    second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
    # Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
    my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")
    b1 = Button(second_frame, text='Make Field',command=(lambda: makeform(second_frame, Data)))
    b1.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=10)
    b3 = Button(second_frame, text='Get Variables',command=(lambda : fetch(Data.Form)))
    b3.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=10)
    b2 = Button(second_frame, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b2.pack(side=TOP, padx=5, pady=10)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have to update the Canvas's `scrollregion` whenever you add items to it; currently you're only doing that when the Canvas itself is resized.

Comment: You need to bind `<Configure>` on `second_frame` instead of `my_canvas` to update the `scrollregion`